# Openedge 11 - deriving custom controls from ultracontrols (infragistics)

Tags: infragistics, progress-4gl, openedge

We're about to switch from Progress 8 to Openedge 11 with Infragistics Ultra Controls.
With our app's specifics , the derivation of some Ultra Controls starts to make sense. I know how to derive classic .NET controls (custom control class, overrides, etc...), but it seem's I'm missing some Progress/Infragistics specific steps here. If I create a new ABL User Control , I can't add Infragistics tool base as a super class. I get presented only with some Infragistics controls ... like AppStyler, DockablePanes, etc.

Googling, as usual with progress came out rather empty. I would appreciate some (any :)) pointers on how to tackle this.

Comment: I dont know, if I understand you problem... do you will create new class, which derived from Progress.Windows.UserControl and at the same time from the Infragistics.ToolBase? the class can inherited only from one parent.... 
I checked the option of inheritance from ToolBase - it going - you must override all constructors from base...
please let me know, what is your problem...

Comment: @firhang This is exactly what i needed.Assurance that it can be done, and done easy. The mistake I did was trying to set up ABL User Control and not ABL Inherited Control. The second was trusting openedge search , where you pick the control that your custom control inherits from. If one types "inf" (for infragistics) in that search box, it comes out blank. Because it searches only from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When searching for the super class (inherits lookup) the search is on the short class name only (like Ultra...). Not starting with the package/name space name.

You may also have to make sure that the class that you plan to inherit from is also available in one of the assemblies that are referenced in your project.